# How to bring an area above the iOS softkeyboard using flex 4.6

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, keyboard, flex4.6

I have a number of UI components in the screen. When i click on a text input in iOS, the keyboard is displayed but it overlaps some of the UI components like another text input and a button. I want all these to be visible to user when the keyboard is displayed. I have tried the keyboard related properties such as needSoftKeyboard, requestSoftKeyboard(),  in flex but none of these seem to work in iOS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but maby it can help someone in the future.

In the application.xml file, there is a setting for the softkeyboard behavior.  One of them is pan, which slides the display up to keep the focused object in view.  There is another one(I cant remember its name right now) that squishes the view so everything stays on screen, but looks squished.  You will probobly have to use pan, and redo your layout slightly so the objects you want to be in view can all fit in that small space.
I recall reading something about the ability to put your view in a scroller, and when the keyboard pans up you will have the ability to scroll through your view to see all the display objects. Other than that there is not really a way to have a full screens worth of content fit above the keyboard when it appears.

Some flex objects dont like to be panned.  TextInputs with the Flex 4.6 Mobile skin do not support panning, and the text will pan out of the component.  I also dont think anything inside a scroller supports panning either